# Write_csv output issues: yyyymmddThhmmssZ instead of yyyymmdd hhmmss

Tags: r, csv, datetime-format, readr

I have been messing around with the datetime formatting, as I have data that goes through daylight savings time. The csv files I read in skip an hour in the spring and then repeat one in the fall. This seems to mess up a loop I am using. So I am tying to see if telling R what timezone the data is in PST and PDT, will help.

I was playing with reading in the data:

```
read_csv("file.csv", locale = locale(tz = "America/Los_Angeles"))
```

I read in of the data inputs the proper timezone, but now I have issues using write_csv.

When I write my datafile it outputs ie. "2011-11-30T14:20:51Z" in the csv datetime column.

I tried to reinstall R/RSTUDIO, readr, and to read in new data without this formatting and write_csv; all with no luck! I am still learning so any tips would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Having read this about four times, I still cannot tell what data you actually start with, what you tried, what you actually got, and what you actually wanted.  I can see where you try to explain those things, but it's too unclear to understand.  I mean, `2011-11-30T14:20:51Z` is one of the ISO 8601 formats for UTC time.  It doesn't need time zone information because it represents a unique point in time.  That's what UTC is for.  You might need to translate UTC to your local time to make it easier to work with, but... I don't understand what you're even asking for here.

Comment: Sorry for the confusing question. I think I figured it out - using readr_csv it will assign date time class to columns and when you use write_csv, if the column is class POSIXct it will format to ISO8601 with a UTC timezone and convert to UTC if the data is not.  I guess I'm not used to seeing that format in a csv file with text characters. Is there a way to override this to act like write.csv, so it doesn't format the date on export?